# Why use "self" and what does it mean?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, self

So, I just started learning Objective-C and I've come across this "self" thing.  I've only ever used C, but I think it's used in java too maybe?  Can someone explain?  Here's an example:

```
- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSString *digit = [sender currentTitle];
    UILabel *myDisplay = [self display];  //why this?
}
```

Why isn't it just this?

```
- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
        NSString *digit = [sender currentTitle];
        UILabel *myDisplay = display;  //why not like this?
}
```

display is a UILabel *

Comment: If you've only used C, and no object-oriented languages, you should read [*Write Objective-C Code*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/WriteObjective-CCode/WriteObjective-CCode/WriteObjective-CCode.html), part of Apple's “Start Developing iOS Apps Today” guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[self display]`, or `self.display`, refers to a *property* / *method* (property is just a shortcut for get/set method anyway) if you have something like this in the .h file

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) UILabel* display;
```

or

```
-(UILabel*)display;
```

Just `display`, or `self->display` refers to an *instance variable*. This is valid when you have declared an instance var like this:

```
@implementation MyClass {
    UILabel* display;
}
```

If you have declared the property `display` in the .h file and haven't changed its default, the corresponding instance var will be `_display` (note the underscore), in which case the following will be the same:
`self.display` and `self->_display`

Answer (score 1):

In this case it's an objective C messaging thing. When you see the brackets it's doing this:

```
[Object Message]
```

Basically self is the object and display is the message your sending it. Sending it a message is like a method call in another language, but a little different under the hood. So something like this:

```
[self doSomethingCool];
```

in objective C would translate to something like this in another language:

```
this.doSomethingCool();
```

of course if running a method on another object you'll replace self with that object like:

```
[myObject doSomethingCool];
```

in a lot of languages you don't really need to have the "this" in front of your method call, it's implied that if you don't include it you're running the method in the object you're working with. I got burned pretty early on when I started with something similar. I had a call to a datalayer method where you could save an object and it would give you an integer back. When I was saving the object I didn't put the self in front of the method call and it was essentially generating a new object and saving it and I wasn't getting the right integer back.

Using "self" just explicitly tells it "I'm using THIS object". Same thing with properties, I always use "self.MyProperty" instead of "MyProperty" because I want to be explicit and make sure I'm using the MyProperty of the object I'm working in. It's semi rare for a defect like that to hit you, where you expect to be using a certain object and the environment thinks you're using another, but man when you run into one it's a head scratcher because everything looks right.

Answer (score 0):

The word *self* refers to the current object, which is your view controller instance in this case, and combining it with a method name, which is *display*, means you are sending the message *display* to *self* which is the view controller. This will invoke the method *display* declared in your view controller instance.

You might declare the display method in your view controller, for example:

```
- (UILabel)display 
{
    //your display method implementation returning UILabel instance
}
```

For the second one, it means you are referring to *display* variable. For example:

```
UILabel *display = [[UILabel alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

`display` is not a `UILabel *` - it might be a *property* with that type, or a *method* which returns a value of that type, but these a rather different things.

You need to go an read something about object oriented programming. The `self` in Objective-C is the *current object reference*, other OO languages call it `this` - both Java and C++ use that name. Understanding objects and methods is fundamental to using any of these languages.

Answer (score 0):

There's a very good explanation of this here:
http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/02/08/understanding-your-objective-c-self.html

The key section for your question is the section on Objective-C 2.0 dot syntax:

> Objective-C Dot Syntax
>
> The dot syntax was introduced with Objective-C 2.0 and generates a lot
>   of debate. A number of experienced and long time Cocoa programmers
>   recommend avoiding it completely. Others such as Chris Hanson have a
>   different view about when to use properties and dot notation.
>   Whichever side of the argument you fall I guess the main thing is to
>   be consistent.
>
> Anyway the main thing to understand about the dot syntax is that the
>   following two statements are doing the same thing:

```
self.timestamp = [NSDate date];
[self setTimestamp:[NSDate date]];
```

> The dot is just a shortcut for the more traditional Objective-C method
>   call. Any time you see a dot you can replace it with the equivalent
>   square bracket method call syntax. It is important to understand
>   however that this is not the same as writing the following:
>
> timestamp = [NSDate date]; Without the self object and the dot we are
>   no longer sending an object a message but directly accessing the ivar
>   named timestamp. Since this bypasses the setter method we will
>   overwrite the timestamp ivar without first releasing the old NSDate
>   object. We will also not retain the new object that we are assigning.
>   Both of these situations are bad!

Keep in mind that the examples were written without using ARC, so there's a lot of references to memory management, retain, release etc. It is however useful to see these examples so that you have some idea of what ARC is doing in the background.

In your example, you are not referring to the actual display property with `[self display]` you are in fact referring to an instance method of the "self" object which in this case is your UIViewController.

Comment: there is very important difference between the `self.timestamp = ...;` and `[self setTimestamp:...];`. the first one _will skip_ the setter to reach the property, the second one _will use_ the setter, but there is more: in the following statement if the `customObject` is nil, the line `customObject.property = ...;` will thrown an exception and `[customObject setProperty:...];` won't in the same situation. so we can say, _there are not the same at all_.

Comment: @holex There is no difference between `self.timestamp = ...` and `[self setTimestamp:...]`.  As stated in [“Dot Syntax Is a Concise Alternative to Accessor Method Calls” in Apple's *Programming with Objective-C* book](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW10): **Dot syntax is purely a convenient wrapper around accessor method calls. When you use dot syntax, the property is still accessed or changed using the getter and setter methods mentioned above**.

Comment: @holex `self.timestamp = ` is just a different syntax for `[self setTimeStamp:...]` - both call the same setter. If however you were to just use `timestamp =` this is when you skip the setter and refer to the property directly. Your second example is correct (I believe), but it is not related to what is being debated.